# How to convert vector back to Sentence using TensorFlow's Universal Sentence Encoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector, nlp, word2vec

I'm using TensorFlow's Universal Sentence Encoder and I want to convert a generated vector back into a sentence. TensorFlow provides a way to go from a sentence to a vector, but I want to reverse this.

For example, if I have a sentence vector like the one below, can I convert this vector back into a sentence?

```
[0.293, 0.239, 0.4834, ... ] --> "The quick brown fox..."
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. The neural network that is used to compute the embedding does numerical operations that are irreversible like a summation. If you sum two numbers and only get the results, you can no longer say what were the inputs to the summation.

If you really don't have access to the original sentence, you try to train a recurrent decoder that will at least approximately reconstruct the vector, but it will be extremely noisy.